# Ошибка MySql #1064 right syntax to use near ''

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

Создаю триггер:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER user_ins AFTER
INSERT ON
  `agr`.oc_customer FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  IF
    (
      NOT EXISTS(
      SELECT
        *
      FROM
        `flowers`.oc_customer
      WHERE
        email = NEW.email
    )
    ) THEN
  INSERT
INTO
  `flowers`.oc_customer(
    customer_group_id,
    store_id,
    firstname,
    lastname,
    email,
    telephone,
    fax,
    PASSWORD,
    salt,
    cart,
    wishlist,
    newsletter,
    address_id,
    custom_field,
    ip,
    STATUS,
    approved,
    safe,
    token,
    date_added
  )
VALUES(
  NEW.customer_group_id,
  NEW.store_id,
  NEW.firstname,
  NEW.lastname,
  NEW.email,
  NEW.telephone,
  NEW.fax,
  NEW.password,
  NEW.salt,
  NEW.cart,
  NEW.wishlist,
  NEW.newsletter,
  NEW.address_id,
  NEW.custom_field,
  NEW.ip,
  NEW.status,
  NEW.approved,
  NEW.safe,
  NEW.token,
  NEW.date_added
) ; IF(
  NOT EXISTS(
  SELECT
    *
  FROM
    `garden`.oc_customer
  WHERE
    email = NEW.email
)
) THEN
INSERT
INTO
  `garden`.oc_customer(
    customer_group_id,
    store_id,
    firstname,
    lastname,
    email,
    telephone,
    fax,
    PASSWORD,
    salt,
    cart,
    wishlist,
    newsletter,
    address_id,
    custom_field,
    ip,
    STATUS,
    approved,
    safe,
    token,
    date_added
  )
VALUES(
  NEW.customer_group_id,
  NEW.store_id,
  NEW.firstname,
  NEW.lastname,
  NEW.email,
  NEW.telephone,
  NEW.fax,
  NEW.password,
  NEW.salt,
  NEW.cart,
  NEW.wishlist,
  NEW.newsletter,
  NEW.address_id,
  NEW.custom_field,
  NEW.ip,
  NEW.status,
  NEW.approved,
  NEW.safe,
  NEW.token,
  NEW.date_added
) ;
END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

При создании выдаёт:

> `#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 117`

Не могу понять в чём проблема

Comment: какая строка 117?

Comment: А где `END IF` ? https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/if.html

Comment: @Mike, действительно, забыл
Уж извините